# Adding active class to current active link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question is available on SO, but I have to ask this.
I have made a plugin for my navigation with several functions and events.
One method is to add an active class to the current link.
The method was working fine before but I have made some changes and now it is no longer working.

**My method is:**

```
$('.nav-menu li a').filter(function(){
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).addClass("active");
```

It's a very simple method but I need to write it again.
There are several functions and an event handler on that plugin.

### There is a some selector working on a click event

```
 $(document).on('click', '.nav-menu li a', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('href') !== '#') {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
          $('#preloader').removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn').fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function() {
              window.location = link;
            }, 1500)
    } else if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
 });
```

Comment: What does your link look like? `<a href="....">link</a>`

Comment: @Bondye yes That ls.

Comment: Do you have other code working with the same selector?

Comment: @Mivaweb yes there is a click event with same selector.That is working

Comment: can you add this code into your question?

Comment: Checking the URL to set classes is generally not a very good idea, it breaks easily if the URL changes just a little bit. If this is different pages you could just hardcode the class instead.

Comment: What did the code look like before you changed it?  When it was still working?

Comment: @talemyn yes it was same like this now

Comment: Is your link's href an absolute url or relative url?

Comment: @adeneo So what should i do?

Comment: Hey that code is working in main script file but not in the plugin :v

Answer (score 0):

May be `this.href` is not giving you the absolute url. I am not sure though. But it is better if you use `indexOf` which will work even if there is a relative url in the href.

```
$('.nav-menu li a').filter(function(){
    return location.href.replace(/#.*/, "").indexOf($(this).attr('href')) != -1;
}).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Try my edited answer, now I am using `attr` method to get the href value.

Comment: Hey that code works in main script file but not in the plugin

Comment: I dont know what plugin is doing so I cannot tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: It may be for the position of the code in the plugin